# Django DeleteView Redirect to Second Previous Page

Tags: python, django, generics

I have my generic deleteview. The user can visit here from the generic updateview, because only button is there. I like to redirect the user to previous page after deletion but the previous page is the updateview and it'll be gone with the deletion.

Is there any way to send the user to second previous page after deletion ?

```
class ActionDeleteView(generic.DeleteView): # action-deleteview
    model = models.Action
    template_name = 'crm/action_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self): # for the message
        message = f'{self.get_object()} is deleted successfully!'
        messages.success(self.request, message)
        previous = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        print('***************** previous: ', previous)
        return reverse_lazy('action-listview')
```

NOTE: The print(previous) in the code returns the updateview

Answer (score 0):

With django's redirect function, you can redirect to any created view, should work for you.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect    

class ActionDeleteView(generic.DeleteView): # action-deleteview
    model = models.Action
    template_name = 'crm/action_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self): # for the message
        message = f'{self.get_object()} is deleted successfully!'
        messages.success(self.request, message)
        previous = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        print('***************** previous: ', previous)
        return redirect('Intended View')
```

Comment: reverse_lazy and redirect make the same transaction. My point is that I can not reach 2 page previous to redirect. That's where I stuck!

Comment: @SemihSARI sorry for the wait, I might be be misunderstanding your question, since you already know the view that serves the page, wouldn't that make your task trivial